# Searching index in list of lists following a list of values - python

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
xs = [[0.6666666865348816, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.5333333611488342, 0.5333333611488342], 
  [0.6428571343421936, 0.7142857313156128, 0.7333333492279053, 0.5714285969734192, 0.5714285969734192], 
  [0.6666666865348816, 0.8666666746139526, 0.7333333492279053, 0.5333333611488342, 0.5333333611488342]]
```

`ss = [0.5333333611488342, 0.5714285969734192, 0.5333333611488342]`

And I will like to get the index in list xs following the values of ss. The result of list that I search is like this :

```
list_result = [[3,4], [3,4], [3,4]]
```

I will appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? Any looping done? Debug outputs?

Comment: welcome to SO. Please read how to ask question, up vote useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please take time to understand [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and list data structure in python.
for your case this code is working. Please understand it.

```
list_result = []
for lst in xs:
    result_list = []
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        for s in ss:
            if s == item:
                result_list.append(i)
                break
    list_result.append(result_list)
print(list_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_result = []
for sub_list in xs:
    list_result.append([i for i, item in enumerate(sub_list) if item in ss])

print(list_result)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 4]]
```